# Python TypeError: < not supported between instances of str and int in training model

Tags: types, instance, data-cleaning, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm encountering an issue when trying to convert an object to a string in Python. Specifically, I'm working with a dataset for a Named Entity Recognition (NER) task (new at this), and I need to convert certain columns to strings for preprocessing. However, I'm facing difficulties with this conversion.

My dataset consists of columns such as 'sentence_id', 'words', and 'labels'. I need to convert these columns to string format to prepare the data for training a NER model.

I need guidance.

This is part of my code:

```
print(train_data.dtypes)
print(test_data.dtypes)
```

sentence_id     int64
words          object
labels         object
dtype: object
sentence_id     int64
words          object
labels         object
dtype: object

```
print(train_data['labels'].unique())
print(test_data['labels'].unique())
```

['O' 'B-SKILL' 'I-SKILL']
['O' 'I-SKILL' 'B-SKILL']

```
model = NERModel('bert', 'bert-base-cased',labels=label,use_cuda=False, args={'fp16': False})

model.train_model(train_data,eval_data = test_data,acc=accuracy_score)
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.train_model(train_data,eval_data = test_data,acc=accuracy_score)

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
351         first = True
352         if _sort_keys:
--> 353             items = sorted(dct.items())
354         else:
355             items = dct.items()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

I've applied data cleaning steps to remove unwanted characters, symbols, and numbers from the 'words' column using regular expressions.